# Further than the Sedenions?

Tags: quaternions

So after the quaternions came to my knowledge, I wonder if you could go any further with the complexity. Turns out you can with the octonions(8D numbers) and sedenions(16D numbers). But are there 32D numbers, 64D numbers, etc.?

Comment: Yes.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction to see what properties are lost with each doubling.

Comment: I'm already not aware of any applications of the sedenions whatsoever (the octonions have some interesting applications to constructing exceptional Lie groups), so I don't particularly see a need to go any farther in this direction. In a related direction you could learn about rings in general, which have many applications: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory